# How do I align these boxes using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row" >
    <div id="box1" class="col-lg-4 box"style="">
        <img src="images/1.png" style="" class="num-img">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">box 1 content</a>
    </div>  
    <div id="box2" class="col-lg-4 box" style="">
        <img src="images/2.png" style="" class="num-img">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">box 2 content</a>
    </div>
    <div id="box3" class="col-lg-4 box" style="">
        <img src="images/3.png" style="" class="num-img">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">box 3 content</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS of the box:

```
.box
{
    height: 130px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is how I want it to look like:
[image]

This is how it looks right now :

[image]

And this is how it looks when I remove the `box` class and write:

```
<div id="box1" class="col-lg-4 "style="">
```

[image]

How do I fix this??

**Update (after adding `margin:0 auto`):**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are possibly overriding the `width` of the `col-lg-4` `divs`, depending on when your `box` css is loaded.  Try

```
<div id="box1" class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="box">
        <img src="images/1.png" style="" class="num-img">
        <a href="Search.jsp" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">box 1 content</a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

This will not force the `col-lg-4` div to have a set `px` width, but instead a `%` with the inner `div` having a set `width`.

If you want to center the blocks within the bootstrap `cols`, add `margin: 0 auto;` to your `box` css.

```
.box
{
    height: 130px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

example using your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8xUL/455/)

Comment: Thanks the boxes are now aligned but the space on left is little less than right i.e. they not in centre. Like in the 3rd screenshot.

Comment: create a plunker/codepen and I can take a look at it

Comment: that is an issue with your `num-img` class, please either update your post with all your code, or create a codepen with a proper working example

Answer (score 1):

Add `col-offset-2` with all col classes and you will see change. change `col-offset-2` as per requirement.

Comment: Yes offset it is used for giving margin for cols. You may write text-center.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can wrap the box in a column like this..

```
<div class="row" >
      <div id="box1" class="col-lg-4"style="">
          <div class="box">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Paris_m_2_jms.svg/50px-Paris_m_2_jms.svg.png" style="" class="num-img">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">box 1 content</a>
          </div>
      </div>  
      <div id="box2" class="col-lg-4" style="">
          <div class="box">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Paris_m_2_jms.svg/50px-Paris_m_2_jms.svg.png" style="" class="num-img">
              <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">box 2 content</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="box3" class="col-lg-4" style="">
          <div class="box">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Paris_m_2_jms.svg/50px-Paris_m_2_jms.svg.png" style="" class="num-img">
              <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">box 3 content</a>  
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.box
{
    height: 130px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row" >
      <div id="box1" class="col-lg-4 text-center">
          <div class="box" style = "display:inline-block">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Paris_m_2_jms.svg/50px-Paris_m_2_jms.svg.png" style="" class="num-img">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">box 1 content</a>
          </div>
      </div>  
      <div id="box2" class="col-lg-4 text-center" style="">
          <div class="box"  style = "display:inline-block">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Paris_m_2_jms.svg/50px-Paris_m_2_jms.svg.png" style="" class="num-img">
              <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">box 2 content</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="box3" class="col-lg-4  text-center" style="">
          <div class="box" style = "display:inline-block">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/Paris_m_2_jms.svg/50px-Paris_m_2_jms.svg.png" style="" class="num-img">
              <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;">box 3 content</a>  
          </div>
      </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CodePen:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbOKKw

Comment: Why have you used `display:inline-block` ?

Comment: display:inline-block is given, because of outer div has given text-align